# Recursively search Directory by name and return path

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I have a directory structure with up to 10 levels (may vary), given the name of the directory, I would like to return the complete path of the first directory that matches the name of the given directory.

```
public function LocalDirSearch($clouse) {
        $path    = $clouse[0];
        $search = $clouse[1];
        $result = $clouse[2];
        $dirs   = glob($path, GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            if(basename($dir)==$search){
                return $dir;
                break;
            }
            $this->LocalDirSearch([$dir,$search,$result]);
        }
    }
```

I made this script but it does not work properly I do not know what exactly it is missing and it runs indefinitely ... no error output...

**Update**

this the directory structure:

```
+--pdf
+---+---i-pdf-0034
+---+---+---form
+---+---+---+---data
+---+---+---+---other
+---+---i-pdf-0045
+---+---+---form
+---+---+---+---data
+---+---+---+---other
+---+---i-pdf-0056
+---+---+---form
+---+---+---+---data
+---+---+---+---other
+--doc
+---+---i-doc-0034
+---+---+---form
+---+---+---+---data
+---+---+---+---other
+---+---i-doc-0045
+---+---+---form
+---+---+---+---data
+---+---+---+---other
+---+---i-doc-0056
+---+---+---form
+---+---+---+---data
+---+---+---+---other
```

function call:

```
$this->LocalDirSearch(['C:/xampp/htdocs/files','i-pdf-0045']);
```

Script to search directory:

```
public function LocalDirSearch($clouse) {
    $path   = $clouse[0];
    $search = $clouse[1];
    $dirs = glob($path . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if (basename($dir) == $search) {
            return $dir;
        }else{
            // return the result of the recursive call
            return $this->LocalDirSearch([$dir, $search]);  
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput of recursive print nav in directory:

```
'C:/xampp/htdocs/files/'
'C:/xampp/htdocs/files/pdf/'
'C:/xampp/htdocs/files/pdf/i-pdf-0034/'
'C:/xampp/htdocs/files/pdf/i-pdf-0034/form/'
'C:/xampp/htdocs/files/pdf/i-pdf-0034/form/data/' #out of search
```

Return:

```
'NULL'
```

Comment: There is a mistake (or typo?) in `return = $dir`, but it doesn't seem to be infinite.

Comment: yea and mistake, i remove '='

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: @Sammitch i saw this, but it work to return file name i not find any script like that i have, that work with nested directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main problems:

1. You don't provide a pattern for glob that will return any subdirectories
2. You don't return the result of the recursive call

which means it will never find your target (unless your target happens to be the directory you start in), so it will never return.

---

Try making the following changes

```
public function LocalDirSearch($clouse) {
    $path    = $clouse[0];
    $search = $clouse[1];
    $result = $clouse[2];

    // add a wildcard to the glob pattern so it will match everything under $path
    $dirs   = glob($path . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if (basename($dir)==$search){
            return $dir;
        }

        // return the result of the recursive call
        if ($subdir = $this->LocalDirSearch([$dir, $search, $result])) {
            return $subdir;
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, `break` is unnecessary after `return`, and `$result` does not appear to be used in the function.

Comment: `$path` is the initial path directory, `$search` is the pattern like string `pdf_files`...

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match for `$search`?

Comment: yea if `$search` = `to pdf_files` i need get the first directory with this name, because i use basename() to compare.

Comment: return NULL or this => ''

Comment: i have update with all example posible with the problem

Comment: Oops, I see what I did wrong, sorry. I'll update the answer.